# references in erlang receive

Tags: erlang

I heard that tagging messages with references in Erlang as shown [here](http://www.erlang.org/course/advanced.html) (see part about references), will prevent the process to go through the all message queue when using "receive". Is that true?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, see OTP-8623 in http://www.erlang.org/doc/apps/erts/notes.html#id65167